# Multithreading help in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port

Basically after every 2 secs i get values in 2 decimal digit by device using serial connection , so i have converted every byte to character then concatenated to second character(byte) received through serial port and then assigned to one textbox out 4 sequently(MB , GC , INS , OU) so what is happening that every time values are updated in MB and OU textbox but not other textbox. So if some can help me through these logic. (Am new to vb so try to be elaborative as possible).

Code:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    cc = Chr(SerialPort1.ReadByte())
    dd = Chr(SerialPort1.ReadByte())
    ee = cc + dd
    ReceivedText(ee)

End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        If c = 0 Then
        If Me.MB.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.MB.Text = [text] 'append text
        End If
            c = 1
        ElseIf c = 1 Then
        If Me.GC.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.GC.Text = [text] 'append text
        End If
            c = 2
        ElseIf c = 2 Then
        If Me.OU.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.OU.Text = [text] 'append text
        End If
            c = 3
        ElseIf c = 3 Then
        If Me.INS.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.INS.Text = [text] 'append text
            c = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would put a breakpoint, you would notice that C is being modified twice per call. One for the "normal" call and an other time for the Invoke. I suggest you move the logic for setting up "c". Place it right after changing the textbox value.

```
Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
    If c = 0 Then
        If Me.MB.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.MB.Text = [text] 'append text
            c = 1
        End If

    ElseIf c = 1 Then
        If Me.GC.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.GC.Text = [text] 'append text
            c = 2
        End If

    ElseIf c = 2 Then
        If Me.OU.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.OU.Text = [text] 'append text
            c = 3
        End If

    ElseIf c = 3 Then
        If Me.INS.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.INS.Text = [text] 'append text
            c = 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I would also suggest you put more meaninfull variable name. Using things like c, cc, ee, doesn't mean much.

You can also reduce your code a little bit. Try not repeating yourself. (note: I did not compile to see if it works).

```
Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
    Dim tbToUpdate As TextBox

    ' This could even be in an array
    Select Case c
        Case 0
            tbToUpdate = Me.MB
        Case 1
            tbToUpdate = Me.GC
        Case 2
            tbToUpdate = Me.OU
        Case 3
            tbToUpdate = Me.INS
    End Case

    If tbToUpdate.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        tbToUpdate.Text = [text] 'append text
        c += 1

        If c == 4 Then
            c = 0
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: c (integer=0(default)) is used as counter so every time it increments i can write new data to new textbox , cc dd and ee are declared as string.

Comment: @MihirGurjar then I would suggest you rename "c" to textboxCounter